# Magento2 include controller to existing signup customer button and also fetch the store config values in observer

Tags: magento2

Can anyone help me how to include a controller to existing customer create signup button, So that i will add some functionality to this controller.

in magento2

I have a Helper data like below:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
   public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
   {

   return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_HELLOWORLD .'general/'. $code, $storeId);
   }
    FIRST_SIGNUP_POINTS = 'test/social_integration/f_signup'; 
   public function Test() { 
     $points = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(selF::FIRST_SIGNUP_POINTS); if($points){
     $points = (int)$points; 
   } 
   return $points; 
   }
}
```

This is my model file name: loyalitytransaction

Thanks

Comment: Use event observer to run addition functions when you create a new customer @shivashankarm

Comment: Can you please share any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

Create a custom module and place this events.xml in the below path

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml

add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Customer\RegisterSuccess" name="observer_customer_register_success"/>
  </event>
</config>
```

then create a file which use to trigger at the time of customer registration successful.

Place the below file in the respective path which has been mentioned in events.xml

> app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/Observer/Customer/RegisterSuccess.php

then add the below code in it

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Customer;
class RegisterSuccess implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\LoyalitytransactionFactory $modelFactory
    )
    {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->modelFactory = $modelFactory;
    }
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
        $custom_value = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('test/social_integration/f_signup', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $this->modelFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $this->modelFactory->setColumnName($custom_value);
        $this->modelFactory->save();
    }
}
```

check log file whether it is correctly triggering or not and you can add functionality which you would like to add after customer successfully registered.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this observer is calling for customer registration

Comment: How to fetch storeconfig values in this observer and save it in my custom table

Comment: This is my model file name TestTransactions

Comment: in my controller it is extending \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action this but in our observer we have implemented  \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface how to agin add extends there

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91200/discussion-on-answer-by-prathap-gunasekaran-magento2-include-controller-to-exist).